# scrollView not working android

Tags: android, scrollview

I see the scroll line but it is not working. This is the code:

What could be the reason?

The layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleshopandsell"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="פריטים שתוכל למכור"
                android:textColor="#880000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />



           <GridView 
               android:id="@+id/gridView1"
               android:numColumns="auto_fit"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
               android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
               android:columnWidth="130dp"
               android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      </GridView>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridView` is also a special type of `ScrollView`.. you should change parent scrollView to Relative/Linear Layout.

Currently Both scrollView and GridView obstruct the proper scrolling.